# How to deconstruct an ES6 module joint export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've run into a little hiccup with an export scenario and I am not sure why.  I may need a Babel plugin to address it but not sure which.

```
// a.js
export function fromA() {}

// b.js
export function fromB() {}

// index.js
import * as a from './a'
import * as b from './b'

export default { ...a, ...b}

// test.js
import all from './index'  
const { fromA } = all // Works

import { fromA } from './index'  // Does not work. Why?
```

I am running through Babel. Here's my rc:

```
{
  "plugins":  [
    "transform-object-rest-spread", 
    "transform-class-properties", 
    "transform-export-extensions", 
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
   ], 
  "presets":  ["latest", "react"]
}
```

It seems that I should be able to destucture in test.js within the import statement as usual but no. If, in index.js, I export individual functions then it woks. As in:

```
import { fromA } from './a'
import { fromB } from './b'
export default { fromA, fromB }
```

However I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Though import syntax looks like deconstruction, it's not. You're exporting an object from your `index.js`, so you can only import it as the whole object.

Comment: The only exception is when you're importing a non-es6 module. Since commonjs modules can only export one variable per module, babel falls back to deconstruction importing them.

Comment: ^ This. Also, `import { fromA } from './index'` won't work because there's no `fromA` export, only default. And `fromA` export can't be achieved with `
`export { ...a, ...b}` because imports and exports are mimicking JS object syntax and supposed to be static.

Answer (score 13):

Though import syntax looks like deconstruction, it's not.

When you're exporting a named variable you can only import it as a named variable. And when you're exporting a default variable, you can only import it as a default one.

For example:

```js
// a.js
export const foo = 1
export const bar = 2
export default { bar: 42, baz: 33 }
```

```js
import { foo } from './a'
// foo = 1
```

```js
import { bar } from './a'
// bar = 2
```

```js
import a from './a'
// a = { bar: 42, baz: 33 }
```

The only exception is when you're importing a non-es6 module. Since commonjs modules can only export one variable per module, babel falls back to deconstruction importing them.

So, since you're exporting a single object from your `index.js`, so you can only import it as the whole object.

---

Probably what you're looking for is an `export * from` statement:

```
export * from './a'
export * from './b'
```

It will re-export all named exports from both modules.